# make submenu wider than main menu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9QE58/) submenu and I would like it so that when the dropdown menu is out it has a width of 100% and covers the whole page. At the moment if I change the width to 100% it just makes it the same width as the main menu.

This is my current HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>    <a href="services.html">Services</a>

                <ul class="sub">    <a href="services.html#branddesign">
                            <li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Design-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" />
                                <br>
                                Brand Design
                            </li></a>
<a href="services.html#brandonline">
                            <li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Online-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" />
                                <br>
                                Brand Online
                            </li></a>
<a href="services.html#brandmarketing">
                            <li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Marketing-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" />
                                <br>
                                Brand Marketing
                            </li></a>
<a href="services.html#brandmanagement">
                            <li><img class="imgcenter" src="images/Brand-Management-Circle-Blue.png" width="100px" />
                                <br>
                                Brand Management
                            </li></a>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="">Clients</a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="">About</a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="">Contact Us</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
    .header {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.nav {
    position: static;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav ul > li:first-child {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6db6e5;
}

.nav li {
    font-family: "eras_demi_itcregular", Arial, Helvetica;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav li:hover a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6db6e5;
    color: #6db6e5;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    height:150px;

}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 23px;
}

.nav ul ul {
    width: 494px;
    background: #7d7c7c;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition:all .5s ease-in-out;    
}

.nav ul ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 129px;
}

.nav ul ul li:last-child {

}

.nav ul ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}

.nav li li { 
  height:130px; 
  -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can make it so that the submenu can be wider than the main menu?

Comment: Try `.nav > ul > li { position: relative; } .nav ul ul { position: absolute; top; 0; left: 0; // width: whatever you want }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
nav ul ul {
    width: 100vw;
    left: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QE58/1/embedded/result/

That should keep it at 100% of the viewport width no matter what the pixel width is.

Comment: that gets the full width but my menu doesn't start at the beginning of the page, it's in the middle and the sub menu starts underneath that, is there any way to make it start at the beginning of the page?

Comment: You could give it a negative value for left. ie, `left: -13px` instead of `left: 0`.